# PowerShell Comparison Operator throwing incorrect value

Tags: powershell, boolean

```
> $a1

Hash
----
9045345C8B84BFC1271FACC4CAE8A145263028C2ECD6F558BEAE841DD3BD116


> $a2

Hash
----
9045345C8B84BFC1271FACC4CAE8A145263028C2ECD6F558BEAE841DD3BD116


> $a1 -eq $a2
False
```

Why would it give false when the Hash property is clearly the same?
Using `-like` works, however, I don't know if it's recommended over `-eq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `$a1 -eq $a2` what you're comparing are 2 objects with a property named `Hash`, what you're looking to do instead is to compare the **value** of the `Hash` property on both objects, you can expand the values of those properties with the member access operator `.`. See [**about Properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.3#property-values).

```bash
$a1 = [pscustomobject]@{
    Hash = '9045345C8B84BFC1271FACC4CAE8A145263028C2ECD6F558BEAE841DD3BD116'
}
$a2 = [pscustomobject]@{
    Hash = '9045345C8B84BFC1271FACC4CAE8A145263028C2ECD6F558BEAE841DD3BD116'
}

$a1.Hash -eq $a2.Hash # True
```

[`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) doesn't implement [`IEquatable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-8.0) so when testing these 2 objects for equality, the default is to [`Object.ReferenceEquals(Object, Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-8.0) and these to objects have a different reference, thus `$false`.

##### Why did `-like` return `$true` ?

Essentially, the right-hand side of the operation (`$a2` in this case), is passed as the `pattern` argument to the [`WildcardPattern` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) coercing the object into a string:

```
@{Hash=9045345C8B84BFC1271FACC4CAE8A145263028C2ECD6F558BEAE841DD3BD116}
```

Then comparing it against `$a1` and when both coerced to a string they look exactly the same.

```bash
$pattern = [WildcardPattern]::new(
    [string] $a2,
    [System.Management.Automation.WildcardOptions] 'CultureInvariant, IgnoreCase')

$pattern.IsMatch($a1) # True
```